# Eclipse setting editor location programmatically

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-plugin

I have an Eclipse RCP application in which I'm writing an editor which opens a palette to let user draw flows. Everything is working  fine with editor itself.

However I have problem with its default opening location in perspective layout.
Although other text based editors (like java, xml editors) opening in the expected places. My new editor is opening in the top position by closing my other views positioned at top alreeady.I want it to be opened in the editor area without closing other views.
my FLowEditor is extending org.eclipse.ui.part.EditorPart.

Does anybody know how can i manage to change its opening behaviour and make it similar to java  editor?

Thanks.

Comment: All declared editors are opened in the same workbench part and you don't have to (can't) do anything about it. What you should be asking is: what am I doing wrong that my editor does not behave as an editor in the workbench?

Comment: How do you define the perspective layout? By `plugin.xml` or `IPerspectiveFactory`? What does it look like, could you post it?

Comment: I am using IPerspectiveFactory and just now i realized that some procedure i am calling in the init part of editor causes this problem.i changed this local procedure and now everything works as expected.Thanks for responses.

Answer (score 0):

Martti is correct....the editor must be in the one location, it is pre-defined.  You can hide this area in a perspective, allowing your views to be full screen, but you cannot move where the editor is displayed (unless perhaps by detaching it so it is standalone).